# Android java Replace all ' to \' in a String

Tags: java, android, string

In my android application I have to generate a query String from data from a EditText and in my case I have to consider **'** inputs as they are create problems in query strings. how can I replace all of the ' s in the string into **\'** so as it does not make troubles.
Hear is an example.

This is my EditText input

```
"Samantha's car's"
```

and I want this to be

```
"Samantha\'s car\'s"
```

how can i do this. in case of more ' s is it possible to check recursively. if so how can I avoid \'s instead of **'**.

Comment: You should handle your queries as prepared statements, there are many pitfalls otherwise

Comment: While this can be done, it is not the best solution. If you get problems in query strings there are methods available that deal with escaping special characters automatically.

Comment: no I don't want to escape those special characters. I want them to be added to the string as I mentioned

Comment: Instead of replacing `'` with `\'`, I used to replace them with `''`. But a better way to deal with queries and SQL commands is to use **bound parameters**. In that case, the conversion is *automatic*, and you don't have to worry about that anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method to replace your as per requirements. This will handle literals correctly as well.

```
String myString="Samantha's car's";
myString.replaceAll("\'","\\\\'");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tested it out using netBeans. This is performing as expected. Can remove the single backslash from the regex though i think..

Comment: Apologies, you're right.  `replaceAll` does treat backslashes in the replacement string specially, so you do need that many.  You could have used `replace`, which doesn't treat backslashes in the replacement string specially, since there's no need for the pattern to be a regex.  I got the two confused.